# Как вы храните найденные решения? и храните ли вообще?

Tags: документация

Допустим, вы несколько дней ломали голову над какой-то задачей. Перерыли весь интернет, спрашивали на форумах, консультировались с техподдержкой. И нашли решение (или костыль). Сохраняете ли на будущее описание проблемы и шаги ее решения? если да, то какими инструментами для этого пользуетесь?

- Wiki?
- Отдельный блокнот в Evernote?
- Описываете решение у себя на сайте или на специализированном форуме?

Как документируете?

Может, руководствуетесь какими-нибудь корпоративными руководствами?

Comment: Использую комментарии в коде.

Comment: использую.

Comment: Я пишу об этом вопрос и ответ на StackOverflow.

Answer (score 8):

Храню нужные куски исходников на винте, рассортированные по директориям. Блога не веду, навороченными тулзами (кроме файл-менеджера) не пользуюсь. Для поиска использую мнемоничные имена директорий, в крайнем случае `grep`.

Я недостаточно вебдванолен?

Comment: Аналогично, еще закладки в браузере и письма самому себе с сылками.

А основной инструмент поиска видимо grep.

Comment: [@минусатор](http://hashcode.ru/users/5517/falstaf/reputation/): откомментируйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: У меня тоже все по папкам, но только папки-  это папки с закладками в хроме. Я более вебдванолен :)

Comment: у меня тоже все в букмарках во только когда нужно как бы не назвал закладку найти бывает сложно. закладки имею свойство разрастаться.

Answer (score 4):

Лично я веду свой собственный блог на blogger.com, скорее всего для себя самого, может кому-то еще понадобиться. Записываю туда решения определенных задач. Если задача не столь велика, чтобы ее описывать в блоге, то пользуюсь Документами Google. Где в отдельном(-ых) фалах записываю идеи/решения.

Comment: Тут уже выше писали про собственный блог. Аналогично начал писать на бесплатном хостинге свои решения. По причине бесплатного хостинга и кучи рекламы (не моей) в поисковики моя информация не выдается, зато я знаю, где её всегда искать. А тот же AdBlock позволяет комфортно смотреть любую страницу. Как говорил один мой друг: "Лучше тупой карандашик, чем острая память".

Comment: Согласен, разве что кроме уточнения что блог на блоггере. Я допустим веду собственный. Но суть остается - блог.

Answer (score 3):

Evernote/Springpad.

А вообще, если я искал решение какой-то проблемы и нашёл его, значит я его применил и всегда смогу найти в git'е в одном из проектов, который вёл.

Comment: @flastaf, тут вопрос шире, чем со сниппетами. Речь не только о программировании, но и об администрировании также.

Comment: На остальное - первая часть ответа.

> Evernote/Springpad.

Answer (score 3):

Я собственную библиотеку пишу.

Если решение сколько нибудь полезное стараюсь максимально абстрагировать, шаблонизировать и поместить в класс наиболее близкий по смыслу.

Времени тратиться гораздо больше на создание такой библиотеки, но сейчас начинаю пользоваться плодами той гигантской работы которую вёл 2 года. Время разработки выросло в 3-20 раз. 
Правда если работаешь с несколькими языками так наверное не получится.

Answer (score 3):

Остаются описания там, где искал - на форумах, напр. (Хабр, Хэш, SO). В частности, если решение никто не подсказал, пишу там же собственный найденный вариант.

Ещё хорошо не в одно лицо искать решение, тогда в курсе несколько человек и потом легче найти концы.

В коде, где это решение воплощено, подробные комменты - это вообще всегда хорошо. Потом всегда можно найти в git'ах / svn'ах.

Answer (score 3):

Сперва вел блог, но все же evernote + кое для чего dropbox удобнее. На чужие ресурсы не полагаюсь.

Comment: "На чужие ресурсы не полагаюсь."
А dropbox и evernote - это разве не чужие ресурсы?

Comment: Здесь под чужими ресурсами я понимаю сам контент, а не сервисы. То есть поисковик гугл будет всегда, а вот найденный в нем результат - далеко не факт. Даже на хабре статьи исчезают бесследно. Поэтому надеяться что найденная ссылка завтра не умрет - глупо.

Answer (score 2):

если вы хотите сохранить инфу, заметки или идеи связанные с информацией из интернета - заметки прямо по листингу и пр., сохранение с тегами и категориями в [diigo.com](https://www.diigo.com/) будет полезным для вас. я очень полюбил этот сервис, крайне удобно.

для хранения и слежения за кодом, написанными вами моделями и классами может быть удобен **github**, или подобные сервисы. удобно также держать такие вещи в облаке, т.е. иметь доступ и удалённо к ним, допустим через телефон. но каталогизировать и упорядочить код - это лучше github

Answer (score 2):

А вот я всегда записываю найденное на обычный стикер и скотчем клею на стену. Если что, то повернул голову - посмотрел - написал в коде. В добавок ещё и зрительная память помогает)
Ну а если найденный материал слишком большой - то ничего страшного, у меня много стикеров :)

Помню, никак не мог сделать выполнение функции каждые 15 секунд. Эх, как же здорово это потрепало мне мозги. В итоге сейчас помню этот код наизусть, а та самая статья в гугле уже на 23 странице (проверял неделю назад).

Answer (score 1):

В мозгах и храню. Пока не мере в памяти храню указатели на само решение, например какие слова надо ввести в гугле чтобы найти искомую статью с решением.

Comment: Помню искал в гугле что-то, везде не то было. Наконец нашел. Запомнил слова. Повторил поиск по тем же словам - вторая или третья ссылка была моя.

Прошло несколько дней (недель) - повторяю поиск - нету той статьи ни на первой, ни на второй, ни на другой странице...

Надо было в закладки ее добавить, а я на поиск понадеялся.

Comment: @ViruSkin, то-то я часто слышу при работе с тем же АльтЛинуксом слова "Как-то я это раньше делал. Помню, несколько часов искал..."

Comment: @BOPOH, @Khvorostin человек спросил как ВЫ храните найденные решения, я лишь ответил как Я храню, не более, я не советовал кому либо делать как я.

Answer (score 1):

всё храню в блокноте :)