# Записная книжка программиста?

Tags: pycharm

Добрый вечер!
Опытные программисты, подскажите как или где вы записываете полезные кусочки кода или функции или еще что нибудь?
Это же должно быть еще и удобно! И желательно наверно что бы из любой точки можно было заглянуть!

Я столкнулся с тем что постоянно подсматриваю банальные запросы SQL (SELECT, UPDATE и так далее) хотя я их знаю.
Спасибо! Не знаю какую метку точно поставить!

Comment: Возможно вы и правы! Но я не знаю какую метку тогда добавить!

Comment: Смотря в чём Вы редактируете код. Если работаете в Sublime Text 3, обратите внимание на плагины [**TODO Review**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/TodoReview) — [**небольшой обзор на русском**](http://comphobby.ru/2012/07/21/sublimetodo-plagin-dlya-organizacii-todo-v-sublime-text-2/) — и [**Sublime Bookmarks**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublime%20Bookmarks). Спасибо.

Comment: В метках свой редактор/IDE укажите.

Comment: [Evernote](https://evernote.com/)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/184668

Comment: У меня `SQLite` база с таблицами под язык; в каждой сниппеты/хаки с названием/описанием, по которому поиск проводить весьма информативно можно. Из консольки спрашивается что-то типа `snippet -js file download` и выводится информация о возможности формировке и скачивания файла на JS.

Comment: Эхх, не успел. Надо было, короткий ответ сначала накатать, пока голосов за удаление не набралось, а потом уже развёрнутый дописывать. @АлександрРублев, [**здесь**](https://github.com/Kristinita/Kristinita.github.io/blob/master/technical_texts/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0.md) полезную информацию, возможно найдёте. Потом допишу этот неопубликованный ответ до полноценной статьи тогда.